# Find all positive integers n for which the number obtained by erasing the last digit of n is a divisor of n?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I know, through this, [image: solution], that all numbers ending on 0 and 11, 12..19, 22, 24, 26, 28, 33, 36, 39, 44, 48, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99 are solutions. But how to prove that all 3- and more-digit numbers which do not end on 0 are not the solution?

Comment: No $2+$ digit number divides a non-zero digit.

Comment: If $a>10$ and $b\neq0$,  then $\frac{b}{a}<1$.

Comment: Because $a$ divides $b$ and $b$ is a single-digit number; therefore $a$ cannot be more than one digit long if $b\ne 0$.

Comment: @lulu can you elaborate on your comment please ??

Comment: @GeorgeLaw As I understand, the question is possible values of $a,b,c$ if $10a+b|100a+10b+c$ and $c\ne0 $,, I cannot relate it with your comment

Comment: @AtulMishra  The given argument shows that $a\,|\, b$ but $b$ is just a single digit.  It follows that, unless $b=0$, $a$ must also be a single digit.

Comment: @GeorgeLaw thanx, got it. Pretty easy as hell, I am even a bit ashamed that I posted it here before thinking twice lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First case**: 
$ 100 \leq n $. 
In this case we $\color{Green}{\text{claim}}$ that
$\color{Green}{\text{the last digit is equal to zero}}$ , 
conversly every integer with the last digit equal to zero 
has the above property.

---

Let

$$ 100 \leq 
n=\overline{  a_m  a_{m-1}  ...  a_1  a_0  }= 
a_m10^m + a_{m-1}10^{m-1} + ... + a_110 + a_0  \  
; \ \ \   
\text{i.e.} \ \ 
2 \leq m $$

with $a_m \neq 0$, 
also on the otherhand let

$$n ^ {\prime}=\overline{  a_m  a_{m-1}  ...  a_1  }= 
a_m10^{m-1} + a_{m-1}10^{m-2} + ... + a_210 + a_1  \  .$$

---

then one can see easily that:

$$\color{Blue} {n=10n^{\prime}+a_0} ,$$

also notice that

$$ a_0 < 10 
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\text{and} 
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
10 \leq n^{\prime},$$

so we can conclude that:

$$a_0  < n^{\prime} 
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
,\text{i.e.}   
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
0  \leq  \dfrac  {a_0}  {n^{\prime}}  < 1 .$$

---

Now notice that:

$$       \dfrac{n}{n^{\prime}}     = 
\dfrac{    10    n^{\prime}    +    a_0}    {    n^{\prime}    } = 
\dfrac{    10    n^{\prime}            }    {    n^{\prime}    } + 
\dfrac{                             a_0}    {    n^{\prime}    } = 
10 + 
\dfrac{                             a_0}    {    n^{\prime}    } 
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\Longrightarrow 
\\ 
\color{Red} 
{       10 \leq \dfrac{n}{n^{\prime}} < 10+1=11       } 
, $$

so we must have: $\color{Red} 
{       \dfrac{n}{n^{\prime}}=10       }$ , 
i.e. $\color{Blue} {n=10n^{\prime}+0}$ ; 
which implies that 
$\color{Green}{a_0=0}$ .

---

---

---

---

**Second case** : $n < 100$, which can be done by a simple calculation!

Answer (score 1):

We are told that $a$ divides $n$, so write $n=ka$.  Then $ka=10a+b, (k-10)a=b.$   If $b \gt 0, k-10 \gt 0,$ so $a$ has to divide into $b$.  Since $b$ is a single digit it cannot be larger than $9$, so $a$ cannot be larger than $9$ and the original number has at most two digits.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_na_{n-1}.....a_1a_0=10(a_na_{n-1}.....a_1)+a_0\\a_na_{n-1}.....a_1|10(a_na_{n-1}.....a_1)+a_0\Rightarrow 10(a_na_{n-1}.....a_1)+a_0=k(a_na_{n-1}.....a_1)$$ It follows $$\frac{a_0}{a_na_{n-1}.....a_1}\in\mathbb N$$
All digit cannot divide a two digit number; in other words
$$a_0=b(a_1)$$ has the solutions given by the OP but $$a_0=b(a_2a_1)$$ has no solution for $a_2\ne 0$